# Flux aggregate function to calculate the difference stops at specific date

Tags: influxdb, flux

I'm trying to learn the flux query language for InfluxDB. I'm using InfluxDB OSS 2.7.

I have a time-series with water consumption usage from iobroker. It reports an ever increasing number in liter and I want to show how many liter I have used per month by using a custom function with aggregateWindow. Here is what I have tried:

```
import "timezone"
import "types"
option location = timezone.location(name: "Europe/Berlin")
from(bucket: "iobroker")
|> range(start: -1y, stop: today())
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "Water_Total" and r["_field"] == "value")
|> filter(fn: (r) => types.isNumeric(v: r._value))
|> difference()
|> aggregateWindow(every: 1mo, fn: sum, timeSrc: "_stop")
|> cumulativeSum(columns: ["_value"])
|> derivative(unit: 1d, nonNegative: true, columns: ["_value"], timeColumn: "_time")`
```

This returns a chart/table which stops at a specific date (26.07.2023)[aggregation per month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh17E.png)
How can I find the issue?

I tried to find issues in the data but cannot find it. [data on a daily basis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHroG.png) it stops here having a statement like

```
from(bucket: "iobroker")
|> range(start: -1y, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "Water_Total")
|> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
|> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: spread, createEmpty: false)
|> yield(name: "l")
```

Using

```
 from(bucket: "iobroker")
 |> range(start: -55d, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "Water_Total")
 |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "value")
 |> aggregateWindow(every: 1d, fn: spread, createEmpty: false)
 |> yield(name: "l")
```

I am getting data from 21.08.2023 onwards.